# Triangle inequality, but the other way

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory

I am going through a proof and there seems to be something quite basic that I am missing. I have 3 complex numbers $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$, and $\alpha_3$ and I'm assuming that $|\alpha_1|\geq|\alpha_2|\geq|\alpha_3|$. As it turns out, I can say that $|\alpha_2|=1$ and that $|\alpha_3|=1/|\alpha_1|$. The next line of the proof says "Therefore,\begin{align*} |\alpha_1|+|\alpha_2|+|\alpha_3|\leq|\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3|+4." 
\end{align*}
To my knowledge, there is no bound on these $\alpha_i$ so I am really struggling to see where exactly this inequality came from (in particular the 4?). Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried to get an idea by considering the case where all three numbers are real and positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true in general. Your "as it turns out" is really the crux of the reason why this works. $$|\alpha_2|+|\alpha_3| < 2$$ So, this implies $$\big| |\alpha_1|-2 \big| \le |\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3| \le \big| |\alpha_1| + 2 \big|$$

So, $$|\alpha_1|+|\alpha_2| + |\alpha_3| < |\alpha_1|+2 \le \big| |\alpha_1| -2 \big| + 4 \le |\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3|+4$$

Comment: There should be $\le$ instead of $=$ in the middle of your last line.

Comment: @amsmath thanks!